# do.call a function in R without loading the package

Tags: r, do.call

I want to `do.call` an (exported) function from a package and need to specify the package and function in the `what` argument as a character string (i.e., when the package is not loaded into my environment or there is a potential function name conflict).

The function name is a character string like `"lme4::lmer"` which specifies **both** the package and the function.

For example, to conditionally call a function (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13992367/2371031)):

```r
FUN = if(TRUE) {
  "lme4::lmer"
} else {
  "nlme::nmle"
}

args.list = list(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), 
                 quote(lme4::sleepstudy))

do.call(what=FUN, args=args.list)
# Error in `lme4::lmer`(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), lme4::sleepstudy) : 
#   could not find function "lme4::lmer"
```

Other ways work but are not what I need:

```
# Load the package and use only the function string 
library(lme4)
do.call("lmer", ...)

# Or calling the function directly: 
lme4::lmer(...)
```

Comment: Try it without the `"` quotes.

Comment: @Frank No dice. The point is that the `what` argument to `do.call` takes a character string, and I'm manipulating the value of that string

Comment: Ok, I don't lmer, but this seems to work: `do.call(getFromNamespace("rleid", "data.table"), list(c(1,1), 1:2))` Gotta break your string into its component parts, though (function, then package).

Comment: do.call(lme4::"lmer", ...) will work. Read ?"::"

Comment: do.call(stringr::str_c, c(tmp, sep = ""))
works! so remove the quotes.

Comment: @amrrs I think the OP is saying that the quotes are there because they (somehow) have the function name as a string and are working with it as such.

Comment: @Frank I think OP is thinking he must supply a string there.

Comment: @Jack I think you need to clarify your example.

Comment: `get("lmer", asNamespace("lme4"))`, but I don't understand why you can't pass `lme4::lmer`.

Comment: example: `importFrom(utils,unzip)`

Comment: `a <- "abs";`  `do.call(base::get(a), list(c(-1, -2)))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't include `::` in the string because `::` is a function. That string isn't evaluated and parsed. `do.call` just assumes a function by that name exists. Just like `::`, `$` is also a function so this doesn't work either

```
a <- list(f = function(x) x+1)
do.call(a$f, list(4))
# [1] 5
do.call("a$f", list(4))
# Error in do.call("a$f", list(4)) : could not find function "a$f"
```

If you want to be able to find functions from namespaces, you can write a helper function that parses values when they contain `::`

```
getfun <- function(x) {
    if(length(grep("::", x)) > 0) {
        parts <- strsplit(x, "::")[[1]]
        getExportedValue(parts[1], parts[2])
    } else {
        x
    }
}
getfun("lme4::lmer")
```

And this should work

```
do.call(getfun("lme4::lmer"), list(
    Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), 
    quote(lme4::sleepstudy)))
```

Comment: I've never used such arcana as these `get*`s, but `getFromNamespace` was what Uwe Ligges recommended a decade ago: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/do-call-method-within-namespace-td797206.html

Comment: @Frank I just looked at the source of `::` and did what it did. I'm sure that would work as well.

Comment: Ah ok, I think your way makes more sense. Looks like `getFromNamespace` is more like `:::` (also grabbing unexported funs).

Answer (score 4):

```
do.call(eval(parse(text="lme4::lmer")), ...)
```

eval with parse will work!

```
> tmp <- expand.grid(letters[1:2], 1:3, c("+", "-"))
> do.call(eval(parse(text='stringr::str_c')), c(tmp, sep = ""))

 [1] "a1+" "b1+" "a2+" "b2+" "a3+" "b3+" "a1-" "b1-" "a2-" "b2-" "a3-" "b3-"
```

Reference: https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/